# how to make 2nd level List marker align with contents of 1st level List

Tags: css, html-lists

I am trying to use `margin` and/or `padding` to let the 2nd level marker align with the 1st level contents.

I don't want to use absolute values for `margin` and/or `padding` because if the font-size changes, there will be an obvious gap between the 2nd level marker and the 1st level contents.

I tried `margin-left:-1em;` in 2nd level OL, but this is an obvious gap.

```
<ol style="border:1px solid red;">
 <li>First Level</li>
  <ol type="a" style="border:1px solid blue;">
  <li>Second Level</li>
  <li>Second Level</li>
 </ol>
 <li>First Level</li>
 <li>First Level</li>
</ol>
```

[image]

**Many thanks to G-Cyr. But I find  there's indent problem.**

```
<ol style="border: 1px solid red;">
 <li>First Level</li>
  <ol type="a" style="padding-left:0; list-style-position: inside; border:1px solid blue;">
  <li>Second Level lines still needs to keep proper indent.</li>
  <li>Second Level</li>
  <li>Second Level</li>
 </ol>
 <li>First Level</li>
 <li>First Level</li>
</ol>
```

[image]

I tried `padding-left:1.1em; list-style-position: outside;`. But the appearance really depends on what font face I use. The following font rendering a gap there.

```html
    <ol style="font: 2em Gill Sans, Gill Sans MT; border:1px solid red;">
     <li>First Level</li>
      <ol type="a" style="padding-left:1.1em; list-style-position: outside; border:1px solid blue;">
      <li>Second Level lines still needs to keep proper indent.Second Level lines still needs to keep proper indent.Second Level lines still needs to keep proper indent.Second Level lines still needs to keep proper indent.</li>
      <li>Second Level lines still needs to keep proper indent.Second Level lines still needs to keep proper indent.Second Level lines still needs to keep proper indent.Second Level lines still needs to keep proper indent.Second Level lines still needs to keep proper indent.</li>
      <li>Second Level</li>
     </ol>
     <li>First Level</li>
     <li>First Level</li>
    </ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

a reset on default `margin` and `padding` should be enough.

```css
ol ol,
li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  /* eventually */
  list-style-position: inside;
```

```html
<ol style="border:1px solid red;">
  <li>First Level</li>
  <ol type="a" style="border:1px solid blue;">
    <li>Second Level</li>
    <li>Second Level</li>
  </ol>
  <li>First Level</li>
  <li>First Level</li>
</ol>
```

or is it just the list-position ?

```css
ol ol,
ol ol li {
  padding-left: 0.5em;
  list-style-position: inside;
```

```html
<ol style="border:1px solid red;">
  <li>First Level</li>
  <ol type="a" style="border:1px solid blue;">
    <li>Second Level</li>
    <li>Second Level</li>
  </ol>
  <li>First Level</li>
  <li>First Level</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: G-Cyr, Great job! the 2nd one works.
But I still wantto keep proper indent for lines of 2nd level texts. I've updated my question. thanks

Comment: @visualPaul I tought you would have understood that you could reset padding values to tune them. i've updated the second snippet. best is to understand how it it works than to have it baked right for you. ;)